# JavaScript - Dynamic To-do list - Editing list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For this To-do list, I am able to add a list. However, once added, I am having issue editing the list that already been added. What I am hoping is when you click Edit, you should able to edit the information and upload the edited information (and making sure the edited information is saved in the local storage when you click Save List to Local Storage). Can someone please help me and go over the JavaScript code and see what I am doing wrong? Below is the HTML, JavaScript and CSS codes:

Here is the Dropbox link if it is easier to download the files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qaxygbe95xk4jm1/AADPO98m4416d-ysSGjNt12La?dl=0

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic To-do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Dynamic To-do List.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Dynamic To-do List.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>

<body onload="loadList();">
    <h1>To-Do List</h1> Click Button to Add List: <a href="#" onclick="showListDiv();">Add List </a>
    <div id="listFormDiv">
        <form id="addListForm">
            List name : &nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="listNameTxt"><br /> 
            Description : &nbsp; <textarea name="description" id="listDescTxt"></textarea><br /> 
            Date: <input type="text" id="listDateTxt"><br /> 
            Urgent (Yes or No) : &nbsp;
            <select id="listUrgentTxt" name="Urgent">
                <option value="Yes"> Yes </option>
                <option value="No"> No </option>
            </select><br /> 
            Category : &nbsp;
            <select id="listCategoryTxt" name="category">
                <option value="School"> School </option>
                <option value="Work"> Work </option>
                <option value="Home"> Home </option>
                <option value="Others"> Others </option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" id="addListBtn" value="Add List" onclick="addList()" />
            <input type="button" id="updateListBtn" value="Update List" onclick="updateList()" style="visibility: hidden" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <a href="#" onclick="saveLists();">Save List to Local Storage</a><br />
        <a href="#" onclick="clearStorage();">Clear Local Storage</a><br />
        <div id="listsDiv">
            Add To-Do list here<br />
            <a href="#" onclick="hideList();">Hide List</a><br />
            <a href="#" onclick="showList();">Show List</a><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
sortableList();

$(function() {
    $("#listDateTxt").datepicker();
});

function loadList() {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("lists"));

    var taskList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lists"));

    if (!taskList) {
        console.log("There are no tasks saved in the local storage");
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++) {
            createListDiv(taskList[i]);
        }
    }
}

//get a reference to the listFormDiv div tag that has the add To-Do List form. list is a global variable that can be access easily from any function
var listFormDiv = getElement("listFormDiv");
var listArray = Array(); //list will hold all the To-do list added through the form
var listIDCount = 0; // list variable will be incremented every time a list is added and will be used to assing a unique ID to every list object.

if (localStorage.getItem("lists")) {
    listArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lists"));
}

function clearStorage() {
    localStorage.clear();
    listArray = [];
}

function getElement(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

//function to show the div with the add to-do list form when the add list hyperlink is clicked onLine
function showListDiv() {
    //var st = window.getComputedStyle(listFormDiv,null);
    console.log(listFormDiv);
    listFormDiv.style.display = "block";
}

//list function adds a list when the "add list" button on the form is pressed - 3rd step
function addList() {
    var listName = getElement("listNameTxt").value;
    var listDesc = getElement("listDescTxt").value;
    var listDate = getElement("listDateTxt").value;
    var listUrgent = getElement("listUrgentTxt").value;
    var listCategory = getElement("listCategoryTxt").value;

    //create an instance of the list object with the values from the form
    var f;

    if (listCategory == "School") {
        f = new schoolTask();
        f.setValues(listName, listDesc, listDate, listUrgent, listCategory, "blue");
    } else if (listCategory == "Work") {
        f = new workTask();
        f.setValues(listName, listDesc, listDate, listUrgent, listCategory, "red");
    }

    console.log("school task is " + JSON.stringify(f));

    //clear the textboxes in the form
    getElement("listNameTxt").value = "";
    getElement("listDescTxt").value = "";
    getElement("listDateTxt").value = "";
    getElement("listUrgentTxt").value = "";
    getElement("listCategoryTxt").value = "";

    var listAddButton = getElement("addListBtn");
    var listEditButton = getElement("updateListBtn");

    console.log(listAddButton);
    //listAddButton.style.visibility = "visible";
    listEditButton.style.visibility = "hidden";
    listFormDiv.style.display = "none";

    //add the new list object to the global listArray.
    listArray.push(f);

    //increment the listID count
    listIDCount++;

    //add the list to the page and pass in the newly created list object to the createListDiv function
    createListDiv(f)
}

// a list object - the second step
function setValues(name, desc, date, urgent, category, color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.date = date;
    this.urgent = urgent;
    this.category = category;
    this.color = color;
}

function list() {}

//list.prototype.name = "blank name";
list.prototype.name = "blank";
list.prototype.desc = "blank desc";
list.prototype.date = "blank";
list.prototype.urgent = "blank";
list.prototype.category = "blank";
list.prototype.listID = "blank";
list.prototype.color = "blank";
list.prototype.setValues = setValues;
//list.prototype.name = "test";

function schoolTask() {
    this.address = "25 Timau Road";
}

inheritFrom(schoolTask, list);

function workTask() {
    this.room = "303f";
}

inheritFrom(workTask, list);

function inheritFrom(child, parent) {
    child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);

}

//create a div tag to represent the new list and add the new div to the existing place holder div on the page
function createListDiv(list) {
    var listDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    listDiv.setAttribute("class", "listClass");

    var nameTxt = document.createElement("DIV");
    nameTxt.innerHTML = "To-do List Name: " + list.name;
    nameTxt.id = "nameTxt" + list.listID;

    var lineBreak = document.createElement("BR");

    var descTxt = document.createElement("DIV");
    descTxt.innerHTML = "Description: " + list.desc;
    descTxt.id = "descTxt" + list.listID;

    var dateTxt = document.createElement("DIV");
    dateTxt.innerHTML = "Date: " + list.date;
    dateTxt.id = "dateTxt" + list.listID;

    var urgentTxt = document.createElement("DIV");
    urgentTxt.innerHTML = "Urgent: " + list.urgent;
    urgentTxt.id = "urgentTxt" + list.listID;

    var categoryTxt = document.createElement("DIV");
    categoryTxt.innerHTML = "Category: " + list.category;
    categoryTxt.id = "categoryTxt" + list.listID;

    var editLink = document.createElement("A");
    editLink.setAttribute("onclick", "editList(" + list.listID + ");"); //Note that we are passing the listID from the list object when calling the editList so we know which list object to fetch to edit when we are editing
    editLink.setAttribute("href", "#");
    editLink.id = "editLink" + list.listID;
    editLink.innerHTML = "Edit";

    listDiv.appendChild(nameTxt);
    listDiv.appendChild(lineBreak);
    listDiv.appendChild(descTxt);
    listDiv.appendChild(lineBreak);
    listDiv.appendChild(dateTxt);
    listDiv.appendChild(lineBreak);
    listDiv.appendChild(urgentTxt);
    listDiv.appendChild(lineBreak);
    listDiv.appendChild(categoryTxt);
    listDiv.appendChild(lineBreak);
    listDiv.appendChild(editLink);

    getElement("listsDiv").appendChild(listDiv);
}

//global variable to remember which element in the listArray we are editing
var listIndex;

function editList(listID) {
    //get the the list object from the array based on the index passed in
    var list;

    //show the update list button on the html form and hide the add list button on the same form
    var listAddButton = getElement("addListBtn");
    var listEditButton = getElement("updateListBtn");
    listAddButton.style.visibility = "hidden";
    listEditButton.style.visibility = "visible";

    //iterate through the listsArray until we find the list object that has the same ID as the id passed in to the function
    for (var i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
        //if the listID in the list object is the same as the listID passed in to the function then assign the object from the array to the list variable in list function
        if (listArray[i].listID == listID) {
            //we found the list with the right ID
            list = listArray[i];
            listIndex = i;
        }
    }

    listFormDiv.style.display = "block";

    getElement("listNameTxt").value = list.name;
    getElement("listDescTxt").value = list.desc;
    getElement("listDateTxt").value = list.date;
    getElement("listUrgentTxt").value = list.urgent;
    getElement("listCategoryTxt").value = list.category;

    //updateList(listIndex);
}

//list function will be called when the update button is pressed on the form

function updateList() {
    //save the changed information from the form into the list object in the array based on the array index passed in
    listArray[listIndex].name = getElement("listNameTxt").value;
    listArray[listIndex].desc = getElement("listDescTxt").value;
    listArray[listIndex].date = getElement("listDateTxt").value;
    listArray[listIndex].urgent = getElement("listUrgentTxt").value;
    listArray[listIndex].category = getElement("listCategoryTxt").value;

    var listID = listArray[listIndex].listID; // get the listID from the list object that is in the listsArray at the specificed index;

    //now reflect the same changes in the DIV that shows the list
    getElement("nameTxt" + listID).innerHTML = "To-do List Name: " + getElement("listNameTxt").value;
    getElement("descTxt" + listID).innerHTML = "Description: " + getElement("listDescTxt").value;
    getElement("dateTxt" + listID).innerHTML = "Date: " + getElement("listDateTxt").value;
    getElement("urgentTxt" + listID).innerHTML = "Urgent: " + getElement("listUrgentTxt").value;
    getElement("categoryTxt" + listID).innerHTML = "Category: " + getElement("listCategoryTxt").value;

    //reset the listIndex to a value that does not exisit in the array index
    listIndex = -1;

    var listAddButton = getElement("addListBtn");
    var listEditButton = getElement("updateListBtn");
    listAddButton.style.visibility = "visible";
    listEditButton.style.visibility = "hidden";

    //reset form div visibility
    listFormDiv.style.display = "none";

    getElement("listNameTxt").value = "";
    getElement("listDescTxt").value = "";
    getElement("listDateTxt").value = "";
    getElement("listUrgentTxt").value = "";
    getElement("listCategoryTxt").value = "";
}

//Sortable list - http://jqueryui.com/sortable/
function sortableList() {
    $("#listsDiv").sortable({
        update: function(updateList) {
            var sortOrder = getElement(list).sortable('listArray').toString();
            console.log(sortOrder);
        }
    });
}

function saveLists() {
    localStorage.setItem("lists", JSON.stringify(listArray));
}

//Hide and Show list
function hideList() {
    var listsDiv = getElement("listsDiv");

    if (listsDiv.style.display == "block") {
        //listsDiv.style.display = "none";
        alert("Find a way to hide the list");
    }
}

function showList() {
    var listsDiv = getElement("listsDiv");
    if (listsDiv.style.display == "none") {
        listsDiv.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```css
#listFormDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 350px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
}

#listsDiv { /*Possible #listsDiv*/
    height: 350px;
    width: 200px;
}

#listDescTxt {
    height: 100px;
}

#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 650px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 500px;
}

.listClass {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 160px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list.listID is assigned "Blank";

coming from this >

```
//list.prototype.name = "blank name";
list.prototype.name = "blank";
list.prototype.desc = "blank desc";
list.prototype.date = "blank";
list.prototype.urgent = "blank";
list.prototype.category = "blank";
Line 145: list.prototype.listID = "blank";
list.prototype.color = "blank";
list.prototype.setValues = setValues;
```

That is why 
when it is assigned here >

```
Line 204: editLink.setAttribute("onclick","editList(" + list.listID + ");");
```

You click the edit button, it is sending not an *ID but a "blank".

You probably want to reassign the id here >

```
Line 110: //Assign the id before you push eg. (f.listID == listIDCount++)
//add the new list object to the global listArray.
listArray.push(f);

//increment the listID count
//listIDCount++; why am I incrementing?

//add the list to the page and pass in the newly created list object to the createListDiv function
createListDiv(f)
```

Comment: Thank you Leroy Thompson for your help. I did the changes you suggested and the edit link worked. However, when I add in more than two tasks, Task 1 and Task 2, and if I edit Task 2, then Task 1 will be edited as well. Task 1 will then be the same as Task 2. 

Secondly, after adding more than one task and when I sort or rearrange the tasks, it works but I get an error message:

Dynamic To-do List.js:359 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortable' of null

Line 359 is 
var sortOrder = getElement(list).sortable('listArray').toString();

What's the reason for these issues?